# Bug template in Bugzilla

Tags: bug-tracking, bugzilla

Is there any way to enforce a template in Bugzilla to guide users fill in bugs descriptions ?

Actually, i'd like to put some markup texts in the bug description field and avoid the creation of custom fields.

I've installed version 3.2rc1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, just check ../enter_bug.cgi?format=guided , which forms an example of the template feature. Half the work is already done for you.

Answer (score 0):

The mechansism described under [6.2.5 Particular Templates](https://www.bugzilla.org/docs/2.18/html/cust-templates.html) (under the section called bug/create/create.html.tmpl and bug/create/comment.txt.tmpl) works pretty well for us.  Even though you say you don't want to create custom fields, adding some arbitrary HTML is easy enough.

Comment: The link is actually [here](https://www.bugzilla.org/docs/2.18/html/cust-templates.html) now.